# For Loop iterate over div in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup

I have am using BS to parse a website of job listings. It works fine, but only returns the first items of div. I want this to iterate over every div with the class named {'class': 'job-item'}. I have read through the documentation and tried a few attempts at trying to get this working, but I am just stuck.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import time

quote_page = 'https://jobbio.com/search/jobs?query=Developer&location=dublin&sector='
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.findAll({'class': 'job-item'})

for div in divs:
        role_box =  soup.find(attrs={'class': 'color-dark-grey'})
        role = role_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
        company_box =  soup.find(attrs={'class': 'color-greenish-blue'})
        company = company_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
        location_box =  soup.find(attrs={'class': 'color-grey'})
        location = location_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
        url_box =  soup.find(attrs={'class': 'job-tile-actions'}).a['href']
        url_root = 'http://jobbio.com'
        url = url_root + url_box
        salary = '-'
        date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        array = {'role':str(role), 'company': str(company), 'location': str(location), 'salary': str(salary), 'date':date, 'url': str(url)}
        print array
```

If I remove the for loop the code executes fine, so I know the scraper works. I just want it to print multiple arrays off for everything on a page. This is eventually going to go into DB where I can query it.

Thanks

EDIT: Using debugger, the issue lies with the loop itself (funnily enough)

```
> /var/www/html/JobScraper/scrape.py(13)<module>()
-> divs = soup.findAll({'class': 'job-item'})
(Pdb) n
> /var/www/html/JobScraper/scrape.py(15)<module>()
-> for div in divs:
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /var/www/html/JobScraper/scrape.py(15)<module>()->None
-> for div in divs:
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) n
> /usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py(404)run()
-> self.quitting = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change all the `soup.find()` in the `for` loop to :

```
divs = soup.findAll(class_= 'job-item')    
for div in divs:

    div.find()
```

you should start the search from `div` tag, not the `soup` tag, `soup` tag is the `root` tag of the HTML document

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I didn't realise about the soup pulling from the head, totally makes sense.
It runs but with no output (same as before). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Great that works thanks! I can't upvote because I'm less than 15, but I will come back in the future and upvote this.

Comment: @nford8 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done. Thanks for that